# YouTube Videos are flickering on Chrome

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, google-chrome, youtube, flicker

I am using a Lenovo IdeaPad U430p with Ubutu 14.04 LTS. There is a GeForce GT 730M built in and there are also some drivers available:

NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.38 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)
NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.38 from nvidia-331-updates (proprietary)
X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)

Whichever driver I use, video in chrome are flickering on fast movement. It seems that the screen is cut in half for a few milliseconds.
I tried enable/display Override software rendering list at chrome://flags/ but it changes nothing.

any advice?

Comment: Can you watch videos on Firefox? Is this just YouTube, or all flash? What version of Chrome is it?

Comment: just testet that in firefox and its way better

Comment: Hmm so chrome bug... Click on the chrome menu (3 horizontal lines, at the top right), and click About Google Chrome - what version do you have (e.eg mine says 'Version 34.0.1847.137')

Comment: It says 35.0.1916.114

Comment: Ooh, I need to update! How long has this been a problem? It might be that the latest release is buggy?

Comment: :) the problem is there since I started using ubuntu

Comment: OH! I should note that its only on my TV Screen connected via HDMI

Comment: Ahh so not chrome :) phew, i was worried what would happen when I update! Try unplugging and replugging? (sorry - obvious ik!)

Comment: actually current stable version of Google Chrome is 35.0.1916.153-1 http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome :-)

Comment: Also you should know Google Chrome Stable starting version 35 ships with `Aura` onboard instead of `GTK+` http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/google-chrome-35-linux-arrives-aura dunno if it's appropriate but I heard positive but also negative comments from people who run a bit old hardware.

Comment: I upgraded to 35.0.1916.153-1 but nothing changed. How is it possible that the pictures behaves different on another screen?

Answer (score 3):

Revisiting this page after a month, the problem was that hardware acceleration wasn't enabled. This is apparent on HTML5 videos too!

Go to `chrome://flags`

Look for “Override Software Rendering List”, i.e. enabling GPU acceleration on unsupported hardware and enable it. Restart Chrome (close the background process if you have that running on the top of the bar) and see if it works for you.

Read more [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/enable-hardware-acceleration-in-chrome.html).